# Aplying and removing filters django

Tags: django, forms, filter

I have `date_from`, `date_to`, `studentA` and `studentB` filters.

I want to be able to filter data using one of them, some of them, all of them or none of them at a time. None of them means the entire data is presented - no filters applied.

Say, I have chosen to filter by date range and submitted. I am presented with data from the chosen period. Now if I clear the form (the date range filter criterion) the entire data should pop up again - since no filters are in use.

To make this working I've defined condition in my `views.py`:

```
if (    form.is_valid() 
    and len(request.GET['date_from']) > 0 
    and len(request.GET['date_to']) > 0
    ): 
    date_from = form.cleaned_data['date_from']
    date_to = form.cleaned_data['date_to']
    attendance = Students.objects.filter(
                        date__range=(date_from, date_to))
```

If I did not have this condition, then, when I had cleared the filters from step above no data would pop up back.

When I have one or two filters, this is not an issue, but as more filters come, the code starts to grow rapidly - I have to make a lot of `elif` statements eg.

```
elif (    form.is_valid() 
    and len(request.GET['date_from']) > 0 
    and len(request.GET['date_to']) > 0
    and len(request.GET['studentA']) > 0
    ): 
    # apply this filter

elif (    form.is_valid() 
    and len(request.GET['studentA']) > 0
    ):
    # apply this one
```

and so on.

My question is, is there any alternative, less verbose, way of applying and removing filters back and forth (I am sure there's) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use django-filter (https://github.com/alex/django-filter) for this kind of thing. It does all the filtering for you. It just gives you a `Form` which you can display.

EDIT:

For a range date filter, (start and end date) you can just add 2 filters, one with `lte` lookup, and one with `gte` lookup. For example:

```
date_start = django_filters.DateFilter(name='{date field to filter}' lookup_type='gte')
date_end = django_filters.DateFilter(name='{date field to filter}' lookup_type='lte')
```

Comment: I've used it for a while but to my knowledge it does not support date range filter with custom dates and this one is essential for me. Thanks for input anyways.

Comment: It does have a `DateRangeFilter`, but it is drop down with options like "This week", "this month", etc. If you want a range filter with one starting date, and another ending date filter, you could just add 2 date filters. (See updated answer)

Comment: You save my day :) I'll tinker with it and come back to accept your answer.Thanks!

Comment: Please take the suggestion from @jproffitt. Either extend your filter or extend the form, but definitely don't lace the view with additional logic.

Comment: Hi again @jproffitt. Forgive me if I am being too pushy. I just got into another problem with django-filter, you seem very knowledgeable on this field, thought you may take a look if you got time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947458/altering-django-filter-default-behaviour

Comment: No problem. I will look into it when I get a chance.