# Altering django-filter default behaviour

Tags: python, django, django-filter

This is a [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) app specific guestion.

Has anyone tried to introduce conditions for the filters to query according to the condition?

Let me give an example:

Suppose we have a `Product` model. It can be filtered according to its `name` and `price`.

The default `django-filter` behaviour is that, as we use more filters and chain them together, they filter data using `AND` statements (it narrows the search).

I'd like to change this behaviour and add a ChoiceFilter, say with two options: `AND` as well as `OR`. From this point, the filter should work according to what a user have selected.

Eg. if a user query for products with `name__startswith="Juice"` `OR` `price__lte=10.00`, it should list all the products with names starting with `Juice` as well as products with price below `10.00`.

`Django-filter` docs say that the filter can take an argument:

```
action

An optional callable that tells the filter how to handle the queryset. It recieves a 
QuerySet and the value to filter on and should return a Queryset that is filtered 
appropriately.
```

which seems to be what I am looking for, but the docs lacks any further explanation. Suggestions please?

@EDIT:

This is `views.py`:

```
def product_list(request):
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('my_app/template.html', {'filter': f})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`action` won't cut it. This callback is used for particular filter field and only has access to that field's value.

The cleanest way would be to create multi-widget filter field, similar to `RangeField`. Check out the [source](https://github.com/alex/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/fields.py#L9).

So instead two date fields you use `name`, `price` and the logic type `[AND|OR]` as fields, this way you have access to all these values at once to use in custom queryset.

**EDIT 1:**

This is a little gist I wrote to show how to query two fields with selected operator.
https://gist.github.com/mariodev/6689472

Usage:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    nameprice = NamePriceFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['nameprice']
```

It's actually not very flexible in terms of re-usage, but certainly can be re-factored to make it useful.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the question. Can you give a quick code example of how this would look like? I think I do not get how to use this `[AND|OR]` logic type as fields.

Comment: @nutship I will update my post with example when I'm code with it myself (since I'm interested in that problem as well). `[AND|OR]` represented  as radio or select field, just treat it as typical filter field and use it's value to construct either AND or OR queryset.

Comment: Thanks. Ah, so basically we construct a queryset is `views.py` and then pass it so the `queryset` variable (instead of the default `Product.objects.all()`)?

Comment: @nutship no no no, you got it wrong, that is internal filter field queryset, which is just a part of the whole queryset. Just take a look at `RangeField` src and try to understand how it works or just wait until I update my post with the snippet.

Comment: I would rather override the `FilterSet` somehow, but there really isn't a good method to override. You could do the `qs` method, but that would be a lot of duplicate code...

Comment: @nutship Does the ChoiceField (AND,OR) apply to all filter fields or do you need more flexibility, like just use the (AND,OR) only between some fields?

Comment: Between 2 fields actually.

Comment: Hi, much obliged for this one. I just glanced on the code, think, will be implementing this in the upcoming week so only then I will be able to fully appreciate it. Great job!

Answer (score 4):

Because of the way the final queryset is constructed, making each filter be ORed together is difficult. Essentially, the code works like this:

FilterSet, [filterset.py line 253](https://github.com/alex/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/filterset.py#L257):

```
@property
def qs(self):
    qs = self.queryset.all()
    for filter_ in self.filters():
        qs = filter_.filter(qs)
```

Filters, [filters.py line 253](https://github.com/alex/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/filters.py#L65):

```
def filter(self, qs):
    return qs.filter(name=self.value)
```

Each filter can decide how to apply itself to the incoming queryset, and all filters, as currently implemented, filter the incoming queryset using AND. You could make a new set of filters that OR themselves to the incoming queryset, but there is no way of overriding the behaviour from the FilterSet side.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make filters work with OR, you should make a subclass of FilterSet and override qs from Tim's answer like this:

```
@property
def qs(self):
    qs = self.queryset.none()
    for filter_ in self.filters():
        qs |= filter_.filter(self.queryset.all())
```

I haven't tested this, but I think you got the idea. QuerySets support bitwise operations, so you can easily combine results of two filters with OR.

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to reply. I'll have to spend a day or two with this and hopefully, make it working.

Answer (score 1):

```
class FileFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ['project']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileFilterSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for name, field in self.filters.items():
            if isinstance(field, ModelChoiceFilter):
                field.extra['empty_label'] = None
                field.extra['initial'] = Project.objects.get(pk=2)
                # field.extra['queryset'] = Project.objects.filter(pk=2)


class FileFilter(FilterView):
    model = File
    template_name = 'files_list.html'
    filterset_class = FileFilterSet
```